# Include only part of a partial view with ASP.NET Razor MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I am using ASP.NET Razor MVC and am using Partial Views for common content that I don't want to update on every single page.

I am using the below syntax to include my partial views:

```
@Html.Partial("PartialView")
```

On a particular partial view, I have two DIVS:

```
<div class="divA">
    CONTENT
</div>

<div class="divB">
    CONTENT
</div>
```

However, I only want to include the content from `divA`.  Can I do something like the following to only include the content from `divA`?

```
@Html.Partial("PartialView", @divA)
```

If not, how can I do so?

Comment: You could split the partial view in two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make the partial strongly typed to a view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public bool ShowOnlyPartA { get; set; }
}
```

and then make your view strongly typed to this model:

```
@model MyViewModel

<div class="divA">
    CONTENT
</div>

@if (Model == null || !Model.ShowOnlyPartA)
{
    <div class="divB">
        CONTENT
    </div>
}
```

and then you could call your partial like this:

```
@Html.Partial("PartialView", new MyViewModel { ShowOnlyPartA = true })
```

or like this:

```
@Html.Partial("PartialView")
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I'll implement it and let you know if it works.

Comment: Awesome. It worked.  I tried it without `@model MyViewModel` and it still worked.  Any reason why?  Would leaving it out lead to issues in the future? I guess I don't understand the need to strongly type the partial view to the view?

Comment: Just kidding.  I'm still seeing a few issues and believe it's because of the model.  I get an `InvalidOperationException` which says something like "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `MyOtherViewModel`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `MyViewModel`.  So it is expecting data from another model, but I only pass data from `MyViewModel`.

Comment: FYI- I got it to work by removing `@model MyViewModel` from the partial view and adding `public bool ShowOnlyPartA { get; set; }` to the base model.  Now each model can reference that method in the base.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent question as well as an answer from Darin. As an alternative, pass a string instead:

```
<!-- View -->
@Html.Partial("PartialView", "divA") 

<!-- PartialView -->
@if (Model == "divA")
{
  <div class="divA">
  </div>
}

@if (Model == "divB")
{
  <div class="divB">
  </div>
}
```