# Alternatives to Partial Views

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There is a requirement to share list items (li) among multiple unordered lists (ul).

The current solution is to create a PartialView for each group of list items to be shared, for example:

```
@*PartialViewOne*@
 <li>item1</li> 
 <li>item2</li> 
 <li>item3</li> 

@*PartialViewTwo*@
 <li>item1</li> 
 <li>item2</li> 

@*ViewOne*@
 <ul class="CustomClassONE">@Html.Partial("PartialViewOne")</ul> 

@*ViewTwo*@
 <ul class="CustomClassTWO">@Html.Partial("PartialViewOne")</ul>
```

Since there are many list items groups, this will require creating many PartialViews. Not that it is difficult to create them but just looking for more efficent way of accomplishing the same thing. What alternatives are out there for using the above technique?

Answer (score 3):

I would advice to create those lists using Controllers and add them to viewmodels for the pages you use, probably create some class that will return a collection of items on demand and put these items to viewmodel. Then display them using `.ComboBoxFor(x=>...)`

Something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
   var viewModel = new ViewModel();
   viewModel.ListItems = listItemFactory.GetItemsForFirstCase(); //populate items you use in your example as PartialViewOne
   return View(viewModel);
}


public ActionResult Search() {
   var viewModel = new ViewModel();
   viewModel.ListItems = listItemFactory.GetItemsForSecondCase();//populate items you use in your example as PartialViewTwo
   return View(viewModel);
}
```

This way your view code will be much cleaner - you will need 1 partial / DisplayTemplate / EditorTemplate for all cases, and all data can be combined in any way you will need.

Comment: That is defiantly an alternative to consider. The only drawback I can see is that this route will require compiling with each minor change made to the list objects.

Comment: That's really not a drawback, when you get down to it. In development, maybe, you'd have to stop and restart debugging, but in production, you'd need to republish either way. You should definitely not be modifying views directly on the server, and ideally, you'd want to precompile the views anyways, meaning you couldn't if you wanted to.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, let us say that in production we needed to change an item that was found to be misspelled; using the suggested route will require republishing the entire application in order to reflect a single changed object; on the other hand, if the list items were saved in plain html in a PartialView, in this case we will only need to publish the PartialView file.

Comment: If you want them changed, you can consider about moving this data to DB, cache it and have a button to reset the cache for them - this way you can edit it any time without problems and without noticable slowdown

Comment: @raderick's comment is a good compromise. Again, you should really not be publishing just a single file. The website is a cohesive unit and should be treated as such. Doing things piece-meal means you never know what "version" your site is truly at.

Comment: @Chris, could you please elaborate on 'version of site'? I have been exposed to the idea of published versions with desktop/wpf applications but not really aware of publishing versions in Web applications. The other day we had to push very small changes to a live site that required publishing a css file and the Layout file. That is it, plain static html files that do not require compiling and removing session data in addition the slow down because of the first hit.  Instant changes are cool, republishing... I am not sure. I think as long as you keep your files checked in...then no worries.

Comment: I meant version in a general sense, though you can literally version your website like any other application if you care to. Simply, I mean there's no indication what files have been modified since the last publish and which haven't. There's no cohesive representation of the site, so if you take the code from source control and redeploy it, you're never sure if you're adding new files, updating existing files or what.

Comment: Additionally, you can avoid the first load penalty by precompiling your site, but that also means you have to publish the whole site as a unit, since precompiled views can't be updated on a one off basis.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, would not the version issue continues even if you publish the entire application. In other words, even if you published the entire site at once, it is still difficult to keep track of files that were published. An example, is that you could publish files that have not been CheckedIn yet to SourceControl, and then some other developer comes later and undo the latest changes of those files. That means the next time you publish or republish, you will lose stuff. I think the version issue relies a lot on different variables: developers, communications, and the flow of work.

Comment: No, I'm talking about the repo and the site being out of band. Let's say dev Joe commits File1 and File2 but only publishes File1, because File1 is a bugfix and File2 is part of a bigger build. Publishing from the repo, means File2 is there, but the current state of the site has no File2. The example is contrived, but it's this kind of thing that's emblematic of a slip-shod deployment process. If File2 was to have some sort of dramatic effect on the site, you'd either be left wondering why the current site isn't showing it or that it suddenly happens when you do a full publish.

Comment: Long and short, enterprise-class web shops do full publishes. The owner of a mom and pop shop's nephew does piecemeal updates. Which do you want to be?

Comment: @ChrisPratt, excuse my ignorance, but what repo stands for? Also, the application I referred to earlier is an enterprise level one. In reality, I publish to a stage server and then when everything is tested, a higher caliber team member, copies the stage files to the live server. Since currently I am the only developer responsible for the application, that might be why I am having difficulty comprehending your example.

Comment: @usefulBee I meant not saving HTML to database, but instead storing your item structure, that you intend to draw in these partial views inside <li> and <ul> tags. Stored in SQL/NoSQL storage as ordinary tables, that you can change with scripts, if you need to update them; get them in RenderAction and pass to Razor to compile into html. I'm strongly against keeping HTML in database. Also repo, ChrisPratt is talking about, stands for repository - svn, git, mercurial, etc...

Answer (score 1):

If the type of data you want to display in the partial are same, you may create a viewmodel to represent that,

```
public class MyCustomList
{
  public string ListHeader {set;get;}
  public List<string> Items {set;get;}

  public MyCustomList()
  {
    Items= new List<string>();
  }
}
```

Then add new properties of this type to your other viewmodels as needed

```
public class CustomerDetailsVm
{
  public string FirstName {set;get;}
  public MyCustomList RecentOrders {set;get;}
}
public class ProductDetails
{
  public string ProductCode {set;get;}
  public MyCustomList SimilarProducts {set;get;}
}
```

And in your Action methods, you will set your view/action specific values to this property

```
public ActionResult CustomerDetail(int id)
{
    var vm = new CustomerDetailsVm { FirstName = "Shyju" };
    vm.RecentOrders = new MyCustomList
    {
        ListHeader = "Recent Orders",
        Items = new List<string>
        {
            "IPad",
            "Beer"
        }
    };
     return View(vm);
}

public ActionResult ProductDetail(int id)
{
    var vm = new ProductDetails { ProductCode = "Accord" };
    vm.SimilarProducts = new MyCustomList
    {
        ListHeader = "Similar Products",
        Items =new List<string>
        {
            "Altima",
            "Camry"
        }
    };
    return View(vm);
 }
```

And in your views

```
@model ProductDetails
<h2>@Model.ProductCode</h2>
@Html.Partial("ListPartial",Model.SimilarProducts)
```

and

```
@model CustomerDetailsVm
<p>@Model.FirstName</p>
@Html.Partial("ListPartial",Model.RecentOrders)
```

And your partial view will be strongly typed to our `MyCustomList` viewmodel

```
@model MyCustomList
<h1>@Model.ListHeader</h1>
<ul>
@foreach(var item in Model.Items)
{
  <li>@item</li>
}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an alternative to PartialViews but rather to the way PartialViews are traditionaly used. Tested and was inspired by the following [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386067/include-only-part-of-a-partial-view-with-asp-net-razor-mvc/). Very interesting approach for extracting static html fragments from a single PartialView.

```
<!-- ViewOne -->
<ul>
   @Html.Partial("SharedPartialView", "ListA")
</ul> 

<!-- ViewTwo -->
<ul>
   @Html.Partial("SharedPartialView", "ListA")
</ul> 

<!-- SharedPartialView that includes all list items -->
@if (Model == "ListA")
{
 <li>item1</li> 
 <li>item2</li> 
 <li>item3</li> 
}

@if (Model == "ListB")
{
 <li>item1</li> 
 <li>item2</li> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another robust alternative as well is to use JQuery to extract html fragments from the SharedPartialView and inject them into the Views:

```
<!-- LayoutView -->
<!-- load fragments/lists PartialView in a hidden div-->
<div style="display:none">@Html.Partial("SharedPartialView")</div>
<!-- append appropriate fragments to multiple elements using JQuery -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var test = $("#ListA").contents();
        test.appendTo("#ulOne, #ulTwo");
    });
</script>

<!-- ViewOne -->
<ul id="ulOne">
</ul> 

<!-- ViewTwo -->
<ul id="ulTwo">
</ul> 

<!-- SharedPartialView that includes all lists -->
<ul id="ListA">
 <li>item1</li> 
 <li>item2</li> 
 <li>item3</li> 
</ul>

<ul id="ListB">
 <li>item1</li> 
 <li>item2</li> 
</ul>
```